# TIA Photodiode SFH7050

Tags: operational-amplifier, transimpedance

I'm working with SFH7050 chip, it contains 3 LEDs and a photodiode.
The datasheet suggests the next circuit:
[image]

But it doesn't mention how to calculate Rf nor Cf. Which values should I use and how are they calculated?

Also, the datasheet says:

[image]

Where should I apply the 5V?

thanks!!

Edit This is the waveform with Rf=100kOhms an Cf=0.1uF:
[image]

And this is what I get with Rf=10kOhms and Cf=0.1uF
[image]

something like the last one is what I'd expect since I'm placing my finger on the sensor trying to measure my heartbeats

[image]

Comment: I didn't see any suggestion in the data sheet for the circuit so maybe you can link the data sheet you have?

Comment: Sure, here it is

https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-2496553/SFH%207050%20-%20Photoplethysmography%20Sensor.pdf

Comment: See: https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tidu535

Answer (score 1):

First, as regards Vr: the general schematic for a TIA looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLZGBp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NOTE - Cd IS NOT A REAL COMPONENT! It represents the capacitance inherent in any physical diode. Cf is needed to counteract the effects of Cd, but typically only a few pF is needed to keep the op amp from oscillating. Anything larger, such as your 0.1 uF will serve to filter out high-frequency noise components which may (or may not, depending on your application) be a distraction from your desired signal.

You ask about the .76 current number from the data sheet. Look more closely at the data sheet - that is the specified response of the diode to a particular power level (0.1 mw/cm^2) and a particular wavelength. If you have a rough idea of how much optical power you will be looking at, you can use this number to size your Rf. Your first scope trace indicates that you are probably using a single-supply op amp with 5 volts as a power supply. Your op amp is not a rail-to-rail op amp, and is saturating at ~3.3 volts.

For a given power level, the current through the diode will be fixed, and the voltage out of the op amp will be proportional to the value of Rf. Note that at 10k, you get about 0.5 volts, so a 100k would give you about 5 volts. But the op amp can't do  that with your power supply, so it saturates at 3.3. If you are curious and want to experiment, get a different  op amp, such as the classic TL081, and provide a dual supply of +/- 15 volts, and you can get an output swing of about +/- 12 volts.

See the AC component of your second scope trace? Have you thought about the frequency of that component? I'll wait while you do.

OK? It's not your heartbeat. It's exactly 50 Hz, and I'll bet you're in the UK. Guess what 50 Hz is? If you answered power line frequency you get a gold star. Your body is picking up the power line radiation and your finger is driving the circuit. And yes, this means that you're going to have to learn some more before you can try detecting your heartbeat.

Now, about Vr. In general, increasing Vr will decrease Cd, and allow increased frequency response from the TIA, since you can then reduce Cf without the op amp oscillating. Or, you can increase Rf for the same Cf and get more sensitivity (gain) from the TIA. However, this will also produce a certain DC leakage current through the diode which will cause a voltage shift in the output. The greater Vr the greater the possible sensitivity, with the drawback of a voltage offset. In your case, since you are only interested in rather low frequencies, you should stick with the anode being grounded (Vr = 0). It is the slowest possible TIA configuration, but his has no DC offset produced by the diode (the op amp is a different story).

Answer (score 0):

That seems like the reverse bias voltage to me if you look at the datasheet parameters. I'm not sure how it works, but I think you should apply it to the anode of the photodiode.

Comment: He said "reverse bias voltage".

Comment: Isn't "reverse bias" when a positive voltage is applied to the cathode?

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, I guess I used the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 0):

That resistor sets the gain.  Think of it like this, whatever current the photodiode is sinking over that resistor causes a voltage drop.  This voltage is your output.

$$-{I}_{in}=\frac{V_{out}}{R_{f}}$$

It may sound funny to talk about gain this way since we are going from a current to a voltage.

The capacitor sets the bandwidth, as it slows the response down.

It makes a low-pass filter that looks like this:
$$\beta=\frac{1}{1+R_fC_fs}$$

VR is the reverse bias for the photodiode (if you need it, it reduces the capacitance of the diode to make is faster).  It is applied to the cathode of the photodiode.  Unless you need the bandwidth, try no bias first.  If you need the bias, you usually use a slightly different circuit (where the anode of the photodiode connects to the opamp instead of ground).

Comment: thanks!

what about VR? where should I apply that voltage?

Comment: @mBedded The reverse bias (Vr) is applied to the photodiode itself.

Comment: See my edit.  It goes to the cathode of the photodiode.

Comment: Now I'm having trouble because as the datasheet says:

0.76µA (RedLED) * 1MOhm = 0.76V

but my Opamp output gets up to 3.3V (saturation)

Comment: There is going to be some amount of "dark current".  You may also be capturing more light than you have estimated.  Lower the feedback resistor.  Try 100 kΩ and see what your response looks like.

Comment: @evildemonic 100kΩ still saturates the OpAmp but 10kΩ gets something closer to what I'd expect since I'm trying to measure my heartbeats. Could you please go on with this "dark current" topic?

Comment: Dark current is just the phenomenon that photodiodes will have some current even if you completely shield it from light.  This current will be amplified into a voltage by your amplifier along with any 'real' signal.  With the levels you are talking about (still saturating at 100 kΩ), I don't think dark current is going to be a big factor here.

Answer (score 0):

> But it doesn't mention how to calculate Rf nor Cf. Which values should I use and how are they calculated?

It does address that just below the picture you linked.  It says to pick the largest possible RF for the bandwidth you need, and then to refer to the datasheet for your opamp to pick the right value of Cf.  The reason for this is that Cf is needed to stabilize the opamp and prevent oscillation, so it depends on the opamp you are using.

> Where should I apply the 5V?

That is the reverse bias for the photodiode, but note that the datasheet also recommends setting it to 0v.  In this case, I would follow the recommendation, at least at first.

Since it seems like you are likely to be stuck picking a reasonable OpAmp, take a look at Analog's transimpedance amplifier design wizard:

https://tools.analog.com/en/photodiode/#

It can suggest sensible parts for the bandwidth and gain you are using, and then gives you the values of Rf and Cf.

Comment: I'm using PSoC 4 BLE so I'm stuck to its internal Opamps

Comment: @mBedded  You are not stuck using those internal opamps.  You have the option to use them if they meet your requirements (which you have not mentioned).  The application note has some requirements (low input noise, etc).  I'd look very carefully at those parts, as the integrated parts may not be designed for what you are doing.

Comment: It's a requirement to my project, otherwise I could be looking for options

Comment: @mBedded In that case, you should be trying to understand if your project is feasible as specified.  It may not be.

Answer (score 0):

`R_F` defines transimpedance of a whole TIA setup; to have V_0 = 1V at output, you need `R_F = V_0/I_PD = 6.58 MegaOm`.  The typical bandwidth of a TIA is given by eq. 3 of [SFH 7050 - Photoplethysmography Sensor Application Note](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-7209844/BioMon%20Sensor%20SFH%207050%20%E2%80%94%20Photoplethysmography%20sensor.pdf).

Note that the bandwidth of the TIA must ensure that the short pulses (typ. 5 µs to 50µs) will get amplified without amplitude distortion, and this requirement defines the typical bandwidth `f_3dB`, you have to calculate `f_3dB` from this requirement. Of parameters of this eq. 3, `C_D` is indicated in the text of this document while `GBP` and `C_TIA` figures you take from a datasheet on the component you will use for TIA opamp.

In the table **Characteristics(T = 25C)** of your question, `V_R` values are photodiode reverse voltages at which photocurrents `I_P` were measured for corresponding excitation wavelengths. The Fig. 11 setup [advises to zero the photodiode bias (page 7, see also fig. 13)](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-7209844/BioMon%20Sensor%20SFH%207050%20%E2%80%94%20Photoplethysmography%20sensor.pdf) in order to minimize a dark photocurrent: the photodiode anode PA goes to ground, the photodiode cathode PC goes to an inverted input of TIA, which is also at "virtual ground" in valid mode of operation.

In the [BioMon Sensor datasheet](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-2496439/SFH%207050_EN.pdf), tabulated `V_R` values are admissible reverse voltages for SFH 7050's LEDs and its photodiode. LEDs must be forward biased in order to emit light.

Comment: I must be ignoring something because with Rf=1Mohm the TIA gets to saturation (3.3V)

Comment: V_0/I_PD is given only for starter, as a rough estimation; certainly, you have to consider the requirements of real circuitry (max V_0), and feedback stability, which GBP and f_3dB calculations are for.

Comment: And, sorry once more, I was wrong in my calculation: V_0/I_PD = 1V/1.3uA = 0.77MOm. 1.3uA is stated as a typical photocurrent in the datasheet. Check up your measurement or simulation, R_F is a transimpedance of opamp in inverted configuration. V_output = I_input*R_F. For R_F = 1MOm and I = 1.3uA V_output = 1.3V.

Comment: I've mounted it on the protoboard and my measurement tool is Analog Discovery 2. The TIA still saturates to V+. I'll add images on the original post because I don't know how to in comments. I've read the op-amp's section on PSoCs datasheet but can't figure it out

Comment: Does your TIA configuration exactly follows the Fig. 11 recommended setup or did you customize it? What product title is of a component you use as the opamp in your TIA implementation?

Comment: "Debugging" tip for TIA setup: I_PD is shown to draw current from an inv input node. The current passes thru PD to the ground. Disconnect PD from the inv input, connect the inv input to a 10 MOhm resistor, the other terminal of the resistor connect to -V_cc of your opamp's bipolar power supply. Measure V_output (V_0). With R_F = 1 MOhm you should have V_0 ca. +V_cc/10.

Comment: Cypress PSoCs? Not quite familiar with Cypress, but may be this is of help: PSoC 1 Selecting Analog Ground and Reference [ https://www.cypress.com/file/125266/download ] : "The PSoC Programmable System-on-Chip operates on a single power supply between 3.0 and 5.25 volts.", AN2219 - PSoC 1 Selecting Analog Ground and Reference [ https://www.cypress.com/documentation/application-notes/an2219-psocr-1-selecting-analog-ground-and-reference ]

Comment: @V.V.T yes, Cypress PSoC CY8C4247LQI-BL483 and the CY8CKIT-042-BLE kit. My TIA configuration is exactly as the fig.11 the component values: Cf=0.1uF, Rf=1MOhm

I've noticed that using Rf=10kOhms  doesn't saturate the op-amp.

As far as I know, the PSoC's op-amp are single power supplied so I'm not able to follow your debugging tip. Let me know if I'm wrong.

SFH7050's application note states that using bursts of pulses instead of one single pulse to drive the LED allows better DC and AC ambient light suppression. Could the problem be related to this?

Comment: May it be that you connected the non-inverting input of opamp and the anode of photodiode to PSoC's V_ss ground? The non-inverting input of the single-power opamp in inverting configuration, and the anode of SFH 7050's photodiode, should be connected to a synthesized "virtual ground"(for example, see output of VDAC8 unit of drawing in CE95383.pdf from a zip file in https://www.cypress.com/file/137906/download , ref. from https://www.cypress.com/documentation/code-examples/ce95383-transimpedance-amplifier-tia-psoc-35lp ).

Comment: Notice that the feedback resistor/capacitor values in this example are not mandatory for your TIA design; you have to consider the value of input current (PD current) in your setup.
The synthesized virtual ground is certainly feasible in PSoC 3 and 5, dont know if it is possible with PSoC 4 BL, would you please advise us on this matter, if you try this path. If all this is the case, you may find useful recommedations of https://www.cypress.com/file/198511/download , p.4 on shared return paths for further development.

Comment: You are not obliged to use DAC to synthesize a "virtual ground" voltage, any method recommended by Cypress guides will do, like voltage divider or external reference.

Comment: You may also find useful application notes on single supply opamp design techniques from Microchip, Analog Devices, Texas Instruments, Maxim Integrated

Comment: @V.V.T I can't believe I hadn't posted the schematic, I'll edit the original question. I connected the non-inverting input of op-amp and the anode of the SFH7050's photodiode to the kit's GND GPIO, I don't understand what you mean by V_ss ground to be honest, I'm reading the kit's datasheet but it doesn't specify it clearly

Comment: 1. About "V_ss ground": see https://www.cypress.com/file/416486/download page 12 Table 1, 16-th row, | pin 55 | VSSA GROUND | Analog ground |; page 16 Figure 7, pin 55 connected to GND symbol; page 40, ...should be connected to ground (VSS)...; etc.

Comment: 2. There are single supply opamps with CM input voltage down to lower rail. Can admit PSoC's opamps are of this kind. Still, to be on the safe side, you can research the configuration with "virtual ground": instead of VSS, connect the PD anode and the opamp's non-inv input to VDD/2. You get this voltage from an opamp connected as voltage follower that replicates a voltage from 1/2 voltage divider. For debugging, you can replace PD with, say, 10MOhm resistor, of which the other terminal you connect to VSS, not to the "virtual ground". With R_F = 1MOhm, the output should be ca. VDD/2 + VDD/20.